# Mostrar imagem dentro do menu mobile bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, imagem

Preciso fazer que quando o usuário estiver em um mobile/tablet/ipad dentro do menu (aqueles 3 risquinhos) apareça uma imagem tipo o menu do Google. Essa é a imagem de como tenho que deixar: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem noção de como adicionar essa foto e nome dentro do menu bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1):

Seria mais ou menos isso? Dei umas pesquisadas sobre algo mais ou menos parecido e dei algumas adaptadas...Só necessita você utilizar como um button e movimentar de acordo com o conteúdo...

```css
body {
  background: #F1F3FA;
}

/* Profile container */
.profile {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

/* Profile sidebar */
.profile-sidebar {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.profile-userpic img {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.profile-usertitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.profile-usertitle-name {
  color: #5a7391;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.profile-usertitle-job {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #5b9bd1;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile-userbuttons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-userbuttons .btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.profile-userbuttons .btn:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
    
.profile-usermenu {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f4f7;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li a {
  color: #93a3b5;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li a i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fafcfd;
  color: #5b9bd1;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.profile-usermenu ul li.active a {
  color: #5b9bd1;
  background-color: #f6f9fb;
  border-left: 2px solid #5b9bd1;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

/* Profile Content */
.profile-content {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 460px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row profile">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="profile-sidebar">
    <!-- SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
    <div class="profile-userpic">
     <img src="http://coletiva.net/wp-content/uploads/legacy/perfil/perfil480.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
    <!-- SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
    <div class="profile-usertitle">
     <div class="profile-usertitle-name">
      Marcus Doe
     </div>
     <div class="profile-usertitle-job">
      Developer
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
    <!-- SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
    <div class="profile-userbuttons">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Follow</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Message</button>
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
    <!-- SIDEBAR MENU -->
    <div class="profile-usermenu">
     <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active">
       <a href="#">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
       Overview </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
       Account Settings </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#" target="_blank">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
       Tasks </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
       Help </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END MENU -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="profile-content">
      Conteudo referente a aba...
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
```